# Infinite Loop with execvp in C

Tags: c, shell, fork, infinite-loop, execvp

This program is supposed to be shell which executes commands entered by the user. My program worked fine until I made it accept flags as well as commands. Now, the program loops infinitely at execvp. Any command entered will do this(I've primarily been testing with ls -l). If it matters, I'm writing this code on a Linux machine using the cc compiler. Here is my current code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<linux/types.h>

#define MAX_LINE 80

int main(void)
{
    char *args[MAX_LINE/2+1];
    char buffer[80];
    char *token=NULL;
    char *whiteSpace = " \t\n\f\r\v";


    while(1)
    {
        fflush(stdout);
        printf("osh> ");
        fflush(stdout);
        scanf("%[^\n]",buffer);

        int count=0;
        token=strtok(buffer,whiteSpace);
        args[count] = strdup(token);

        count+=1;
        while((token=strtok(NULL,whiteSpace))!=NULL)
        {
            args[count]=strdup(token);
            count+=1;
        }
        args[count]=NULL;

        pid_t pid = fork();
        if(pid==0)
        {
            if((execvp(args[0],args))==-1)
            {
                printf("Error\n");
                exit(1);
            }
        } else if(pid>0) {
            if(args[count-1]=="&")
                wait();
            else
                waitpid(pid,0,0);       
        } else {
            exit(1);
        }


    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any help or direction is greatly appreciated

Comment: you have some typo in your code. you write `strtoke` instead of `strtok`.

Comment: you can use [GNU readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html), it create history, tab completion, ... for you and read line correctly for you. bash use it as it's main component.

Comment: sorry that was just a typo, thats just an error putting it into here. not in my actual code

Comment: You cannot compare strings with `if(args[count-1]=="&")`.  Use `if(!strcmp(args[count-1],"&"))`.  The logic in this case is boken: `&` should not be passed as an argument to `execvp`, `wait` takes an argument.  Use `waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG)`.  Also include `<sys/wait.h>` and `<sys/types.h>` instead of linux specific `<linux/types.h>`.  `fflush(stdout)` is useless. You don't check for buffer overflow in `scanf`, nor when scanning arguments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting the first input you are not clearing the input buffer. so this is the reason for the infinite loop.

After entering the first input new line will be there in `input` buffer. After processing first input then buffer will give the `\n`.

```
scanf("%[^\n]",buffer); // This scanf will not get the input.
```

So `buffer` will contain the first command user gave. so it will process with that input.

Make this line end of the `while` loop or after the `scanf`.

Declare the variable `int c;`

```
    while((c=getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);// for clearing the buffer until newline or End-Of-File character.
```

Or else you can use like this,

```
 scanf(" %[^\n]",buffer); // to skip the white space character.
        ^
        |
```

Answer (score 0):

In the scanf function repeatedly `\n` will be running so you have to use following

```
    scanf(" %[^\n]",buffer);
```